# Azure DevOps: how to be notified/emailed when a selected branch fails for a build pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops

How do I configure Azure DevOps to send me a 'build failed' email whenever the pipeline fails on my *master* branch?

I'm not interested in failures on other branches but, if everything's working properly, the pipeline should never fail on my *master* branch. Currently, team members can only spot intermittent failures on the master branch if they happen to be looking at the Pipelines web page in DevOps.

It seems you can't specify a branch or branches of interest when setting up notification subscriptions; e.g., see [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/it-is-not-possible-to-filter-build-notifications-o/605898?viewtype=solutions). Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a straight forward way with build-in feature to do that.

As a work around, you could use "Send Email" extension task with condition set on failure of master branch.

Email Report Extension:

[image]

Custom Condition:

[image]

```
and(failed(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
```

If you would like a DevOps build-in feature, help to vote: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/ability-to-filter-build-notifications-on-branch-na/606346

Comment: Thanks! I presume you mean this extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=epsteam.EmailReportExtension)? Unfortunately I'm not an admin so can't try that right now. I guess the situation is also complicated by pipelines being allowed to have multiple `checkout` statements. I couldn't upvote the built-in feature suggestions because unfortunately they're both closed.